# Converting a float to a fraction as a string

Tags: algorithm, f#

I was inspired by [this video by Matt Parker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7LKy3lrkTRA) to use the [Farey Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence) to convert a float into a string representation of a fraction, how did I do? How well did I follow F# workflow and patterns (I'm new to the language)? Can it be done better, or rather, how would a "professional" F# developer write this function? Thanks in advance!

```
let toFraction num =
  let rec farey n0 d0 n1 d1 =
    let n2 = n0 + n1
    let d2 = d0 + d1

    match (n2 / d2) with
    | x when abs (x - num) < 1e-5 -> string n2 + " / " + string d2
    | x when x < num -> farey n2 d2 n1 d1
    | x when x > num -> farey n0 d0 n2 d2
    | _ -> "" // Compiler detects "incomplete pattern matches on this expression without this wildcard, 
    // maybe this is where my method can be improved?

  farey 0. 1. 1. 1.
```

Additionally, this problem assumes the input `num` is in the set `0 <= num < 1`

Comment: Additionally, this problem assumes the input `num` is in the set `0 <= num < 1`

Comment: How would it handle `1e-6`?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much to say about the function and algorithm it self. It's an ordinary recursive function - with tail call - which is optimal for recursive functions.

I don't find a string as return value really useful. Instead I think, I would return a tuple of two integers representing the numerator and denominator

```
let toFraction (num: float): (int * int) = etc...
```

Alternatively you could define a discriminated union as something like:

```
type Fraction = Fraction of int * int
```

... used like:

```
let toFraction num =
if num <= 0.0 || num >= 1.0 then
    failwith "Invalid input"
else
  let rec farey n0 d0 n1 d1 =
    let n2 = n0 + n1
    let d2 = d0 + d1

    match float n2 / float d2 with
    | x when abs (x - num) < 1e-10 -> Fraction(n2, d2)
    | x when x < num -> farey n2 d2 n1 d1
    | x when x > num -> farey n0 d0 n2 d2
    | _ -> failwith "Something went completely wrong" // just to fulfill the pattern matching - it should never happen

  farey 0 1 1 1
```

and called as

```
let (Fraction(num, denom)) = toFraction value
printfn "%d / %d" num denom
```

As shown, I've chosen to run `farey` with integers instead of floats. You should test if that is more efficient than using floats.

---

> `match (n2 / d2) with`

You don't need the parentheses.

---

> `num` is in the set `0 <= num < 1`

`0 = num` is an edge case that is calculated wrongly to

```
1 / 100001
```

If you want `0` to be included in the domain, you need to start `faray` with the values `-1 0 1 1`. Then it will return `"0 / 1"`.

---

Even though you specify in the comment, that it is assumed that `num` should be between zero and one, you should guard against invalid input, especially because invalid input may result in an infinite recursive loop.